# Facing issue while mapping list within list in xml to xml mapping using mule dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-el, dataweave

While I am transforming one xml to another and doing mapping list within list elements.I am getting one exception .

"Cannot coerce a :string to a :object (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler"

Input xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT>
       <transaction>
          <id>www</id>
          <timestamp>20160512 200939</timestamp>
          <sender>ghh566</sender>
       </transaction>
       <identification>
          <R3number>88898</R3number>
          <enterpriseId />
          <sourcesystemid>ffff</sourcesystemid>
          <sourcesystemobjectid>999089</sourcesystemobjectid>
       </identification>
       <details>
          <newTransaction>N</newTransaction>
          <type>siiii</type>
          <organizational>
             <salesOrg>1223</salesOrg>
             <currency>RUPEE</currency>
          </organizational>
          <description>
             <internal>jhjb hjgjhg jkhjh</internal>
             <external>jhhgjhb</external>
             <project>owdoie</project>
          </description>
          <dates>
             <validFrom>2016-04-05</validFrom>
             <validTo>2017-04-30</validTo>
             <fixedValue>0000-00-00</fixedValue>
          </dates>
          <creditTriggerEvent>S</creditTriggerEvent>
       </details>
       <rules>
          <ZCOM_AGR_RULES>
             <rule>
                <ruleType>923</ruleType>
                <agreementItem />
                <ruleNumber />
                <quantities>
                   <minimum />
                   <maximum />
                </quantities>
                <firstRecordA />
                <application />
                <conditionType>dddd</conditionType>
                <salesOrg>1000</salesOrg>
                <distributionChannel />
                <division />
                <endCustomerNumber />
                <serialNumber />
                <soldTo>
                   <ZCOM_AGR_SOLD>
                      <id>990888</id>
                      <addressNumber>2132435</addressNumber>
                      <name>dsfdg fdg</name>
                      <streetAddress>hu78hj k</streetAddress>
                      <postalCode>5654</postalCode>
                      <city>sfds</city>
                      <country>sdsa</country>
                      <phone>555-555-5555</phone>
                      <languageKey>E</languageKey>
                      <district />
                      <houseNumber>poio aaed</houseNumber>
                      <region>iii</region>
                   </ZCOM_AGR_SOLD>
                    <ZCOM_AGR_SOLD>
                  <id>777787</id>
                  <addressNumber>121223</addressNumber>
                  <name>dsfdg fdg</name>
                  <streetAddress>hu78hj k</streetAddress>
                  <postalCode>5654</postalCode>
                  <city>sfds</city>
                  <country>sdsa</country>
                  <phone>555-555-5555</phone>
                  <languageKey>E</languageKey>
                  <district />
                  <houseNumber>poio aaed</houseNumber>
                  <region>iii</region>
               </ZCOM_AGR_SOLD>
                </soldTo>
                <shipTo>
                   <id />
                   <addressNumber />
                   <name />
                   <streetAddress />
                   <postalCode />
                   <city />
                   <country />
                   <phone />
                   <languageKey />
                   <district />
                   <houseNumber />
                   <region />
                </shipTo>
                <upc />
                <catalogNumber />
                <discountSchedule />
                <priceGroupCode />
                <priceFamily />
                <requested-discount-netPrice />
                <delete />
                <customerRate />
                <priceChange />
                <dates>
                   <validFrom>2016-04-05</validFrom>
                   <validTo>2017-04-30</validTo>
                   <fixedValue>0000-00-00</fixedValue>
                </dates>
                <condition>
                   <type />
                   <calculationType />
                   <approved-discount-netPrice>0.00000</approved-discount-netPrice>
                   <unitOfMeasue />
                   <conditionitemindex />
                   <additionalvaluedays />
                   <fixedvaluedate />
                   <maxiumSalesOrdersPerConditionRecord />
                   <numberOfIncrementalScale />
                   <scaleNumberForPricing />
                </condition>
             </rule>
          </ZCOM_AGR_RULES>      
          <ZCOM_AGR_RULES>
             <rule>
                <ruleType>920</ruleType>
                <agreementItem />
                <ruleNumber />
                <quantities>
                   <minimum />
                   <maximum />
                </quantities>
                <firstRecordA />
                <application />
                <conditionType>rrrr</conditionType>
                <salesOrg>1000</salesOrg>
                <distributionChannel />
                <division />
                <endCustomerNumber />
                <serialNumber />
                <soldTo />
                <shipTo>
                   <id />
                   <addressNumber />
                   <name />
                   <streetAddress />
                   <postalCode />
                   <city />
                   <country />
                   <phone />
                   <languageKey />
                   <district />
                <houseNumber />
                   <region />
                </shipTo>
                <upc />
                <catalogNumber />
                <discountSchedule>B5</discountSchedule>
                <priceGroupCode />
                <priceFamily />
                <requested-discount-netPrice>0.00</requested-discount-netPrice>
                <delete />
                <customerRate>0.44</customerRate>
                <priceChange>X</priceChange>
                <dates>
                   <validFrom>2016-04-05</validFrom>
                   <validTo>2017-04-30</validTo>
                   <fixedValue>0000-00-00</fixedValue>
                </dates>
                <condition>
                   <type>rrrr</type>
                   <calculationType>A</calculationType>
                   <approved-discount-netPrice>0.35000</approved-discount-netPrice>
                   <unitOfMeasue>%</unitOfMeasue>
                   <conditionitemindex />
                   <additionalvaluedays />
                   <fixedvaluedate />
                   <maxiumSalesOrdersPerConditionRecord />
                   <numberOfIncrementalScale />
                   <scaleNumberForPricing />
                </condition>
             </rule>
          </ZCOM_AGR_RULES>      
       </rules>
    </ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT>
```

Data weave script code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%type dtfield = :string { format: "yyyyMMdd" }
%namespace ns0 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
%namespace ns1 FlexiWebService
---
{
    ns0#Envelope: {
        ns0#Header: {
            ns1#AuthHeader: {
                Username: "dssdfdf",
                Password: "dfff"
            }       
        },
        ns0#Body: {
            Z_IDDO735_IRM_AGRMNTS01: {
                IDOC: {
                    '_-IRM_-AGMTK01': {
                        (TRANS: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.newTransaction as :string) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.newTransaction?,
                        (BOART_AG: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.type) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.type? ,
                        (AMTNUM: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.identification.sourcesystemobjectid) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.identification.sourcesystemobjectid?,
                        (AGMTNUM_EXT: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.description.external as :string) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.description.external?,
                        (AGMTTXT: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.description.internal) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.description.internal?,
                        (VALID_FROM: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.dates.validFrom as :dtfield replace "-" with "") when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.dates.validFrom?,
                        (VALID_TO: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.dates.validTo as :dtfield replace "-" with "") when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.dates.validTo?,                
                        '_-IRM_-AGMTK02': {
                            ZIDDO735_AGMTK02: {
                                (FV_DATE: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.dates.fixedValue as :dtfield replace "-" with "") when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.dates.fixedValue?,
                                (TDOBNAME: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.creditTriggerEvent) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.creditTriggerEvent?       
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    E1EDK14: {
                        (ORGID: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.organizational.salesOrg) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.organizational.salesOrg?,
                        ZIDDO735_E1EDK14: {
                            (CURR: payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.organizational.currency) when payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.details.organizational.currency?
                        }
                    },
                    ((payload.ZCOM_IDD2565_AGREEMENT.rules.*ZCOM_AGR_RULES default []) map {

                        E1KOMG:{

                        KVEWE: $.rule.firstRecordA,
                        KOTABNR: $.rule.condition.type,
                        KAPPL: $.rule.application,
                        VKORG: $.rule.salesOrg,
                        VTWEG: $.rule.distributionChannel,
                        EAN11: $.rule.upc,
                        KONDM: $.rule.discountSchedule,
                        EVRTP: $.rule.agreementItem,
                        HIENR: $.rule.endCustomerNumber,
                        POSNR: $.rule.ruleNumber,
                        ANZSN: $.rule.requested-discount-netPrice,
                        VKGRP: $.rule.priceGroupCode,
                        ZIDDO735_E1KOMG_QUANTITY: {
                            TDID_MIN_QTY: $.rule.quantities.minimum,
                            TDID_MAX_QTY: $.rule.quantities.maximum
                        },
                        ZIDDO735_E1KOMG: {
                            ZIDD0735_SHIP_TO_KUNWE: {
                                LAND1: $.rule.shipTo.country,
                                NAME1: $.rule.shipTo.name,
                                ORT01: $.rule.shipTo.city,
                                REGIO: $.rule.shipTo.region,
                                TELF1: $.rule.shipTo.phone as :string replace "-" with "",
                                ADRNR: $.rule.shipTo.addressNumber,
                                SPRAS: $.rule.shipTo.languageKey,
                                STRAS: $.rule.shipTo.streetAddress
                            },

                            (ZIDD0735_KNA1_DETAILS:  $.rule.soldTo.*ZCOM_AGR_SOLD default [] map {

                                    KUNNR: $.id,
                                    LAND1: $.country,
                                    NAME1: $.name,
                                    ORT01: $.city,
                                    PSTLZ: $.postalCode,
                                    REGIO: $.region,
                                    TELF1: $.phone as :string replace "-" with "",
                                    ADRNR: $.addressNumber,
                                    SPRAS: $.languageKey,
                                    STRAS: $.streetAddress
                                }) when ($.rule.soldTo !="" and $.rule.soldTo.*ZCOM_AGR_SOLD as :object !="")
                            },
                        E1KONH: {                       
                            DATAB: $.rule.dates.validFrom as :dtfield replace "-" with "",
                            DATBI: $.rule.dates.validTo as :dtfield replace "-" with "",
                            E1KONP: {
                                KSCHL: $.rule.conditionType,
                                KRECH: $.rule.condition.calculationType,
                                KBETR: $.rule.condition.approved-discount-netPrice,
                                KONWA: $.rule.condition.unitOfMeasue,
                                ZAEHK_IND: $.rule.condition.conditionitemindex,
                                VALTG: $.rule.condition.additionalvaluedays,
                                VALDT: $.rule.condition.fixedvaluedate,
                                KLF_STG: $.rule.condition.numberOfIncrementalScale,
                                KLF_KAL: $.rule.condition.scaleNumberForPricing
                            }
                        }
                    }})     
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually what is happening, fields under ZIDD0735_KNA1_DETAILS-node of output xml is mapped to fields under ZCOM_AGR_SOLD and ZCOM_AGR_SOLD is List of data or you can say array.In output where I have values for ZCOM_AGR_SOLD, I am getting data under ZIDD0735_KNA1_DETAILS, but instead of the repeated values of ZIDD0735_KNA1_DETAILS I am getting ZCOM_AGR_SOLD under ZIDD0735_KNA1_DETAILS with all input xml node names not output node names.This is happening with this field only. rest everything is working fine.

Comment: can you provide your dataweave script and the sample input xml?

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar scenario:

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1108/dataweave-date-conversion-from-string.html

Could it be that your dates are the one causing the exception?